# Mongo DB with NOrm vs SQL Server 2008 R2 with linqToSQL in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, mongodb, norm

do you have any experience with mongo db and NOrm in asp.net mvc? i have read that mongo is faster than sql server 2008. I know that mongo is schema free and i can use the type List. Why do I have to continue to choose sql server? mongo db appear more fast and more flexible

Comment: "i have read that mongo is faster than sql server 2008" - I read the streets were paved with gold.... In what context? Do you require relational integrity?

Answer (score 1):

You miss the context: there are tasks where MongoDB would suit better than SQL Server, but there are some where SQL would be better. You should understand the details of you problem to choose the right tool.